# Apache, Tomcat : Loadbalancing not working, failed to connect with Tomcat

Tags: linux, debian, networking, apache-httpd, tomcat

I am working on loadbalancing 2 servers. Both of them are on different domain names. I have configured load balancing for them according. Currently, I am getting failed to make connection. What am I doing wrong? 
Also, what configuration do I need to make on server2 for this to work?

Error log :

```
Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to IP:8090 (IP) failed
```

Apache 000-default.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName domain.de
ServerAlias www.domain.de
SSLEngine on
SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyVerify none
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.de/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.de/private.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.de/chain.pem
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
       BalancerMember http://IP:8090 route=server1
       BalancerMember http://IP:8009 route=server2
</Proxy>
 ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
 ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://cluster/
ProxyPreserveHost On
</VirtualHost>
```

Tomcat :

```
<Connector port="8443" enableLookups="true" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" SSLEnabled="true" 
maxThreads="200" disableUploadTimeout="true" connectionTimeout="36000"
compression="off" sslProtocols="TLS" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1" ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_
ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
 TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"
 compressionMinSize="1024" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" 
keystoreFile="/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.de/KEYSTORE.jks" keyPass="PASS" keyAlias="tomcat" keystorePass="PASS" URIEncoding="utf-8"/>

    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="server1">
```

Comment: `ProxyPassReverse / balancer://cluster/` should be `ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster/`

Comment: @RomeoNinov : Thanks. Changed that. I am still getting (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to server 1 IP. Can you tell me what configuration should I use on Server2? Because this would mean that apache is contacting server 2 on non-standard ports, blocked by default.

Comment: Disable firewall or open those ports for communication

Comment: @RomeoNinov : Okay, but it's not working for either of the servers. Any ideas what is wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTTPS connector is running on port 8443 and AJP on 8009, not on 8090.

**Edit:**

```
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
       BalancerMember ajp://SERVER1_IP:8009 route=server1
       BalancerMember ajp://SERVER2_IP:8009 route=server2
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/

# I think you can remove these lines
#ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster/
#ProxyPreserveHost On
```

Comment: I thought proxy-balancer works with jvmRoute, but I tried to change the file 000-default.conf to point at 8443, still no luck, and no error log as well this time.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your AJP connector on 8009. But still, in your Apache config are 8090 (server1) and 8009 (server2) defined. If the posted Tomcat config is from server1, then you have to change the port to 8009 in the Apache config as well and change the protocol to "ajp://".

Comment: After changing it to 8009 for Server1, I get :  [ajp-nio-8009-exec-1] org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpMessage.processHeader Invalid message received with signature [18245] inside Tomcat. Inside Apache I get :  AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /

Comment: Change the protocol to "ajp://" like in [Apache Module mod_proxy_ajp](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html)

Comment: Looks like it's gonna work now. I had to a2enmod proxy_ajp. I just have 1 question. Do I need to open ports for AJP on server2 or can I do this virtual host on server2? What's the configuration required on server2?

Comment: What do you mean with open ports? The config on Tomcat2 is the same as on Tomcat1 (besides the different IP). Just replace `jvmRoute="server1"` with `jvmRoute="server2"`. Did you remove the two lines ProxyPassReverse and ProxyPreserveHost?

Comment: I removed them. It's working really good for server1, but not for server2. Connection timed out: AH00957: AJP: attempt to connect to Server 2 IP has failed. I increased maxtimeout, but still doesn't help. Please note, server 2 is on a different IP address, and different domain name.

Comment: Then you might need to open port 8009 in your firewall (both sides I guess).

Comment: I gave the command : /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8012 -j ACCEPT   , saved the iptables, restarted tomcat on server2, still no luck. Can't reach server2.

Comment: I will try with https. Thanks for your help. :-)